# Couldn't find constructor 'Jiffy'

Tags: flutter, xcode, jiffy

my codes are as you can see above. But " timeAgo: Jiffy(json['date']).add(hours: 6).fromNow()," my code gives an error where Jiffy is. How is the solution to the error? If anyone knows, I would be very grateful if you show me the solution to the error by making changes to my codes.

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:jiffy/jiffy.dart';
import 'package:wordpress_app/config/wp_config.dart';

class Article {
  final int? id;
  final String? title;
  final String? content;
  final String? image;
  final String? video;
  final String? author;
  final String? avatar;
  final String? category;
  final String? date;
  final String? timeAgo;
  final String? link;
  final int? catId;
  final List? tags;

  Article(
      {this.id,
      this.title,
      this.content,
      this.image,
      this.video,
      this.author,
      this.avatar,
      this.category,
      this.date,
      this.timeAgo,
      this.link,
      this.catId,
      required this.tags});


  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Article(
      id: json['id'] ?? 0,
      title: json['title']['rendered'] ?? '',
      content: json['content']['rendered'] ?? '',
      image: json['custom']["featured_image"] != false
        ? json['custom']["featured_image"]
        : WpConfig.randomPostFeatureImage,
      video: json['custom']['td_video'] ?? '',
      author: json['custom']['author']['name'] ?? '',
      avatar: json['custom']['author']['avatar'] ?? 'https://icon-library.com/images/avatar-icon/avatar-icon-27.jpg',
      date: DateFormat('dd MMMM, yyyy', 'en_US')
        .format(DateTime.parse(json["date"]))
        .toString(),

        //Jiffy.parse('date').fromNow(),
            //timeAgo: Jiffy(json["date"]).fromNow(),
      timeAgo: Jiffy(json['date']).add(hours: 6).fromNow(),
      link: json['link'] ?? 'empty',
      category: json["custom"]["categories"][0]["name"] ?? '',
      catId: json["custom"]["categories"][0]["cat_ID"] ?? 0,
      tags: json['tags']

    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem:

Your code gives you the error: `Couldn't find constructor 'Jiffy'` because there's no `Jiffy()` constructor in the jiffy package's [API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/jiffy/latest/jiffy/Jiffy-class.html) as used in this line:

```dart
timeAgo: Jiffy(json['date']).add(hours: 6).fromNow(),
```

### Solution:

Use the [Jiffy.parse()](https://pub.dev/documentation/jiffy/latest/jiffy/Jiffy/Jiffy.parse.html) constructor to parse the date string from the `json` like this:

```dart
timeAgo: Jiffy.parse(json['date']).add(hours: 6).fromNow();
```